# Creating A Module Block For Magento's Welcome Message

Tags: magento, module

I found this very nice tutorial here: http://www.phparrow.com/magento/magento-create-a-simple-module/ on creating a simple Magento Module. I was hoping I could figure out how to put Magento's default welcome message into a module. See, it appears Magento's default welcome message is part of the header because when you look at the layout with template paths turned on the welcome message doesn't have a template of it's own.

The reason I want to add the welcome message to a module is because my page cache caches the header and along with it the welcome message. The welcome message has "Welcome..." then "Welcome...(Customer Name)" then "Welcome...(not Customer Name?)" etc.

The page cache will cache what ever it happens to cache! I mean it might cache a customers name on one page and some other state on another page.

The code in the header.phtml is:

```
<p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getWelcome() ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p>
```

I need to somehow add this to a "module block" so I can tell my page cache not to cache this block. Understand?

The tutorial above explains how to create a module very well but it creates a "new page" and I need to some make a module for this welcome message.

Thank you

Comment: "my page cache caches the header" ... what caching module are you using?

Comment: I'm using this:  http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/zoom-full-page-cache-1742.html It really makes your pages fly but it's tricky. I'm also using another one but it isn't fast as Ezoom.

Comment: I got my module to display the Welcome message but I'm now having troble getting it to display on to the header. I've added this to my local.xml: <reference name="header">
         <block type="welcome/welcome" name="welcome" as="welcomeHome" template="mba/welcome.phtml"/>
 </reference> and then this to my header: <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcomeHome') ?> but no luck.

Comment: By the way, I just added the "as" part I really don't know how "as" works. I think you just make it up. I've also tried <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?> No luck with that either.